# Syntax of DateAdd

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use Excel the DateAdd function to find **the next working day**.

It provides the same result whether you use d, w or y for the period argument.

I tried the following code, and get identical results in all 3 columns.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 9
        Debug.Print i;
        Debug.Print DateAdd("d", i, #9/10/2009#);
        Debug.Print DateAdd("w", i, #9/10/2009#);
        Debug.Print DateAdd("y", i, #9/10/2009#)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Result:
    1 11/09/2009 11/09/2009 11/09/2009
    2 12/09/2009 12/09/2009 12/09/2009
    3 13/09/2009 13/09/2009 13/09/2009
    4 14/09/2009 14/09/2009 14/09/2009
    5 15/09/2009 15/09/2009 15/09/2009
    6 16/09/2009 16/09/2009 16/09/2009
    7 17/09/2009 17/09/2009 17/09/2009
    8 18/09/2009 18/09/2009 18/09/2009
    9 19/09/2009 19/09/2009 19/09/2009

Extract from the documentation:
    Returns a Variant (Date) containing a date to which a specified time interval has been added.

```
Syntax  
DateAdd(interval, number, date)  
...  
interval Required. String expression that is the interval of time you want to add.   
....  

The interval argument has these settings:  

Setting Description   
yyyy Year   
q Quarter   
m Month   
y Day of year   
d Day   
w Weekday   
ww Week   
...
```

Comment: I know what ww and yyyy do ! that is not the question.
I want to get the next weekday (or working day).

Comment: @Patrick weekday != working day.  Adding a weekday to a date simply increments to the next day of the week. e.g. adding one to a friday gives a date for saturday. It's equivilent to adding one day.  Can you point out any documentation that would suggest otherwise?

Comment: Edited my answer a small bit...

Comment: @Glenn: I added to the original question an extract from the help, stating that the first argument is an INTERVAL OF TIME. From this, I understand that "d" is adding a day, and "w" is adding a weekday. Otherwise it would be stupid to have both.

Comment: Could you not just use a conditional based on the day of the week, rather than the DateAdd function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the confusing language of the DateAdd documentation. DateAdd does *not* add workdays. "W" will only add *n* number of days (as you discovered). You can either roll your own function, or do the following:
In Excel, go to Tools>Add Ins and turn on the Analysis Tool Pack for VBA.
In the VBE, go to Tools>References and set a reference to atpvbaen.xls. 
Now you can use the WorkDay function in VBA.

```
Public Sub Test()
    MsgBox CDate(Workday(Date, 3))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is "ww" for week and "yyyy" for year.

Corrected code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 9
        Debug.Print i;
        Debug.Print DateAdd("d", i, #9/10/2009#);
        Debug.Print DateAdd("ww", i, #9/10/2009#);
        Debug.Print DateAdd("yyyy", i, #9/10/2009#)
    Next i
End Sub
```

**From the documentation:**

The syntax for the DateAdd function is:

```
DateAdd ( interval, number, date )
```

interval is the time/date interval that you wish to add. It can be one of the following values:

```
Value   Explanation
yyyy    Year
q   Quarter
m   Month
y   Day of the year
d   Day
w   Weekday
ww  Week
h   Hour
n   Minute
s   Second
```

number is the number of intervals that you wish to add.

date is the date to which the interval should be added.

Answer (score 0):

Your example will add the same number to three different versions of today. "d" represents the current date. "w" represents the day of the week such as 1 for Sunday(default). "y" represents the day of the year. Sept 16 is day 259 of 365 this year.

In order to get what it looks like you're going for do this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 9
        Debug.Print i;
        Debug.Print DateAdd("d", i, #9/10/2009#)    ' adds i days
        Debug.Print DateAdd("ww", i, #9/10/2009#)   ' adds i weeks
        Debug.Print DateAdd("yyyy", i, #9/10/2009#) ' adds i years
    Next i
End Sub
```

Outputs:

```
 1 9/11/2009 9/17/2009 9/10/2010 
 2 9/12/2009 9/24/2009 9/10/2011 
 3 9/13/2009 10/1/2009 9/10/2012 
 4 9/14/2009 10/8/2009 9/10/2013 
 5 9/15/2009 10/15/2009 9/10/2014 
 6 9/16/2009 10/22/2009 9/10/2015 
 7 9/17/2009 10/29/2009 9/10/2016 
 8 9/18/2009 11/5/2009 9/10/2017 
 9 9/19/2009 11/12/2009 9/10/2018
```

EDIT: Take a look [here](http://www.mvps.org/access/datetime/date0012.htm) for some workday math

Comment: Wrong. The arguments represent an interval, "w" being a weekday, as stated in the documentation.

Comment: From the docs...
To add days to "date", you can use Day of Year ("y"), Day ("d"), or Weekday ("w")

The DateAdd function won't return an invalid date. The following example adds one month to January 31:

DateAdd("m", 1, "31-Jan-95")

In this case, DateAdd returns 28-Feb-95, not 31-Feb-95. If date is 31-Jan-96, it returns 29-Feb-96 because 1996 is a leap year.


From my immediate window:
? DateAdd("ww", 2, #9/10/2009#)
9/24/2009

Answer (score -2):

DateAdd("w" doesn't work as expected - Microsoft acknowledged it and posted a workaround at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/115489

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer which explains the issue in your link